# Unknown Expected identifier

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have taken over a project and am fairly new to cocotouch. I was looking throught the code trying to understand things. I didn't think I changed anything but when I went to run It came up with three build errors (it had run just a few minutes before with no problems). The second two seemingly related to the first:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol MapViewDelegate;  //Expected identifier or '(' before 'protocol'

@interface MapView : TTImageView
{
    id<MapViewDelegate> mv_delegate;  //Cannot find protocol declaration for 'MapViewDelegate'
}

@property (assign) id<MapViewDelegate> mv_delegate;  //Cannot find protocol declaration for 'MapViewDelegate'

@end

@protocol MapViewDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)mapView:(MapView *)mv pressedAt:(CGPoint)point;
- (void)mapViewFinishedLoading:(MapView *)mv;

@end
```

I am using XCode4 which I have just switched to but have had working since the switch.

What is going on here?

Comment: I dont think this is your problem. Where are you including this file?

Comment: There was an extra character in the file that I am including this file in. I feel pretty stupid now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MapKit.framework` has been added to the project?

Comment: No there was a problem in the including file.